# CocoaPods spec Validation error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am creating a private cocoa pod for this below is the pod spec.

My Podspec is

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'RSCrashAdapter'
  s.version  = '1.0.0'
  s.platform = :ios, ‘6.0’
  s.summary  = ‘Crash Reporting Tool’
  s.homepage = 'http://rsjs001:7990/scm/boot/rcrai.git'
  s.author   = { ‘Sushree Swetanka’ => ’s’ushree.swetanka@rishabhsoft.com }
  s.source   = { :git => 'http://rsjs001:7990/scm/boot/rcrai.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.license      = { :type => 'New BSD License', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.source_files = '*.{h,m}'
  s.requires_arc = true
end
```

And I am getting the following error in my terminal: in evey spec it gives me error..

```
$ pod spec lint

 -> samplePod.podspec
    - ERROR | [spec] The specification defined in `samplePod.podspec` could not be loaded.


[!] Invalid `samplePod.podspec` file: samplePod.podspec:3: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
  spec.version          = ‘1.0.0’
                               ^
samplePod.podspec:3: syntax error, unexpected tFLOAT, expecting '('
  spec.version          = ‘1.0.0’
                                  ^
samplePod.podspec:4: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
  spec.license          =  :type => 'BSD' 
                                   ^
samplePod.podspec:6: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
  spec.authors          = 'Tony Million' => 'tonymillion@gmail.com'
                                           ^
samplePod.podspec:8: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
...pec.source           =  :git => 'https://github.com/tonymill...
...                               ^
samplePod.podspec:8: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
.../tonymillion/Reachability.git', :tag => 'v3.1.0' 
...                               ^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.


Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation.
```

Please help me on solving the spec error....

Comment: As stated in an answer these quotes are invalid. You need to edit this is a text editor that does not automatically insert typographic quotes.

Comment: @Myaaoonn did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: @JulianKról  After changing ‘ to ' Also I found error on '=>'. Still I am struggling in between for making a podspec and import that in my Project

Answer (score 4):

You should put a version number exactly between this character `"` ("1.0.0") also your `‘` should be `'` not any other.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with the “ and ” symbol in your pod file when you open it in TextEdit. Just update all “ and ” with " and ".

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using the wrong podspec file name.

```
pod lib lint WrongPodName.podspec
```

But the right pod name is

```
pod lib lint MyPodName.podspec
```

You need to type `ls` command and check the exact podspec filename.

Answer (score 0):

At long last got the answer.
open the podspec in xcode and replace all the quotes in it and type it again.
textEdit changes the quotes to its quotes which are not supported by cocoapods.